# Replacement character � in DB firebase (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, character, angularfire

I use AngularJS and angularfire (for google firebase). My web-application work with usual CRUD operation. But, when I get data (previously recorded by this application) replacement character symbols (�) appear in the text. If I replace them, they reappear.
Why is this happening? How to fix it?

When I change one object. The changes also in other (non-related objects in the database). These changes and replace the usual characters on "replacement character".

Comment: possibly not using utf-8 charset in page?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I use <meta charset="UTF-8"> on y html page. I have to prescribe somewhere else?

Comment: This is a simple angular code (like ng-model='database.variable' or $scope.databaseObject.name = text from the input)

Comment: We also found this weird behavior. Has OP found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I did not find a solution to the problem (